# How to validate contact form 7 field from functions.php file in WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a number field in contact form 7. It must be 11 digit number and first two digit must be 24 or 42. Please tell me how can i do this from `functions.php` file. This is my regular expression `^(24|42)\d{9}$` . But i can't use it on `functions.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/ for general information on form validation. Assuming your field has the `type="number"` and a `name="eleven-digits"` your filter could look like:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_number', function( $result, $tag ) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );
    if ( $tag->name = 'eleven-digits' && preg_match( '^(24|42)\d{9}$', $result ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} );
```

If you want a more detailed answer, you should add more detail in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I have made some change and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
 add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_number', 20, 2 );

function custom_number( $result, $tag ) {
$tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

if ( $tag->name = 'eleven-digits' ){
    $number = isset( $_POST['eleven-digits'] ) ? trim( $_POST['eleven-digits'] ) : '';
    if (!preg_match( '/^(24|42)\d{9}/', $number )) {
       $result->invalidate( $tag, "Enter correct number." );
    }
}
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added expression `$` at the end to not allow more than 9 digits, it was like this:

```
/^(24|42)\d{9}$/
```